# Random Forests Decorrelation

Tags: random-forest, ensemble-learning

In Random Forests , you choose out of m features at each node not the complete feature-set. This is said to de-correlate the predictors. Intuitively I understand it but is there any statistics behind when can be say the predictors will be de-correlated and how we can prove in this case this is the scenario

Answer (score 0):

Random forest tries to improve on bagging by de-correlating the trees and reduce variation, so it can select randomly the predictor and form the tree
typically m= log2 P where p is number of features, we cant see the randomly selected predictor logic since it will taken care by algorith